# How to refine a method from a class inside a module

Tags: ruby, refinements

I want to refine a methoded located in a class inside a module, but despite the fact of trying to refine the class, I cannot have the refined code to run:

```
module App
  module Entities
    class User
      def self.name(name)
        puts "Original name: #{name}"
      end
    end
  end
end

module RefinedUser
  refine App::Entities::User do
    def self.name(name)
      puts "Refined name: #{name}"
    end
  end
end

class Runner
  def original
    App::Entities::User.name('Forest')
  end

  using RefinedUser

  def refined
    App::Entities::User.name('Forest')
  end
end

r = Runner.new
r.original
r.refined
```

Output:

`Original name: Forest
Original name: Forest`

Answer (score 1):

You need to refine App::Entities::User with his `singleton_class`. Because `name` is a class method.

```
App::Entities::User is ok.

module RefinedUser
  refine App::Entities::User.singleton_class do
    def name(name)
      puts "Refined name: #{name}"
    end
  end
end

using RefinedUser

class Runner
  def refined
    App::Entities::User.name('Forest')
  end
end

r = Runner.new
r.refined
=>Refined name: Forest
```

Comment: No, But I've seen the same situation before.